# How to solve the following set of equations to find values of a1, a2, and a3

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear, numerical-value

i am new to Mathematica, Can some one kind enough to show me how to solve the following set of nonlinear equations to find a1, a2, and a3..

```
ClearAll;
v1 = 0.25;
eqn = {
       (Cos[a1 Degree] - Cos[a2 Degree] + Cos[a3 Degree]) -v1 == 0,
       (Cos[3 a1 Degree] - Cos[3 a2 Degree] + Cos[3 a3 Degree]) == 0,
       (Cos[5 a1 Degree] - Cos[5 a2 Degree] + Cos[5 a3 Degree]) == 0
      };

 (* Please, i need to know what commands follow from here, thanks *)
 (*Note that a1 < a2 < a3 <π/2 and that a1,a2, and a3, may all be decimal numbers.*)
```

Note that a1 < a2 < a3 <π/2 and that a1,a2, and a3, may all be decimal numbers and degrees not radians

Comment: Please note that a1, a2, and a3, will all be degrees not radians. thnks

Comment: It might be easier to solve in radians and then convert to degrees.

Comment: to solve should i use solve or NDsolve or Nminimize

Comment: In my opinion it should be FindRoot, however, you should specify the initial values of parameters a1,a2 and a3

Answer (score 4):

One can solve the trigonometric system by converting it to a polynomial system with the usual trick of letting `c` and `s` denote cosine and sine, respectively, and adding the constraint `s^2 + c^2 == 1`.

```
sol0 = Solve[Flatten@Join[
   TrigExpand@eqn /. {Cos -> c, Sin -> s},             (* convert to polynomials *)
   c[#]^2 + s[#]^2 == 1 & /@ {a1, a2, a3},             (* pythagorean constraint *)
   {0 <= c[#] <= 1, 0 <= s[#] <= 1} & /@ {a1, a2, a3}  (* first quadrant constraint *)
   ],
 Join[c /@ #, s /@ #] &@{a1, a2, a3}];                 (* prescribe variables *)
Length@sol0  (* number of solutions *)
(*  2  *)
```

The solutions are numerically challenging and result in complex numbers.  The following turns real `Complex` numbers into `Real` numbers (as well as replace the real `1.` by the integer `1`).

```
realize = # /. x_Complex /; Im[x] == 0 :> Re[x] /. (1.) -> 1 &;

systems = sol0 /. {c -> Cos, s -> Sin} /. Rule -> Equal;
N@N[systems, 16] // realize
(*
  {{Cos[a1] == 0.126411, Cos[a2] == 0.644596, Cos[a3] == 0.768185, 
    Sin[a1] == 0.991978, Sin[a2] == 0.764524, Sin[a3] == 0.640228},
   {Cos[a1] == 0.768185, Cos[a2] == 0.644596, Cos[a3] == 0.126411,
    Sin[a1] == 0.640228, Sin[a2] == 0.764524, Sin[a3] == 0.991978}}
*)
```

Using `Solve` to solve these systems ought to be straightforward, but the symbolic numbers on the right-hand sides are so complicated that it takes way too long to finish.  Instead, it's much easier to solve by hand:

```
sol = Cases[#, Sin[v_] == s_ :> v -> ArcSin[s]] & /@ systems;
N[sol, 16] // realize
(*
  {{a1 -> 1.444046302394822,  a2 -> 0.8703021240983367, a3 -> 0.6947954385269770},
   {a1 -> 0.6947954385269770, a2 -> 0.8703021240983367, a3 -> 1.444046302394822}}
*)
```

Check numerically (the symbolics are quite complicated and run too long):

```
eqn /. sol // N[#, 32] &
(*  {{True, True, True}, {True, True, True}}  *)
```

---

*Addendum:*
You can simplify the process by specifying `Cos[a1]`, `Sin[a]`, etc. as variables and skip `c` and `s`.  I think normally there is some risk to this, since built-in transformations of trigonometric functions might be applied, as far as I know.

```
sol0 = Solve[Flatten@Join[
     TrigExpand@eqn,                                        (* convert to polynomials *)
     Cos[#]^2 + Sin[#]^2 == 1 & /@ {a1, a2, a3},            (* pythagorean constraint *)
     {0 <= Cos[#] <= 1, 0 <= Sin[#] <= 1} & /@ {a1, a2, a3} (* first quadrant constraint *)
     ],
   Join[Cos@#, Sin@#] &@{a1, a2, a3}];
systems = sol0 /. Rule -> Equal;       (* systems have the same value as above *)
```

The rest is as above.

Answer (score 2):

Reduce simply and rapidly finds a solution to this without the user needing to understand TrigExpand or other more complicated reworking of the problem.

```
v1 = 1/4;
Simplify[N[Reduce[{
  Cos[a1] - Cos[a2] + Cos[a3] - v1 == 0, 
  Cos[3 a1] - Cos[3 a2] + Cos[3 a3] == 0, 
  Cos[5 a1] - Cos[5 a2] + Cos[5 a3] == 0, 
  0 < a1 < a2 < a3 < Pi/2}, {a1, a2, a3}]]]
```

It then produces a somewhat confusing result:

```
C[1] \[Element] Integers && a2 == 0.870302 && a3 == 1.44405 &&
((a1 == -0.694795 + 6.28319 C[1] && 0.11058 < C[1] < 0.249093) ||
 (a1 == 0.694795 + 6.28319 C[1] && -0.11058 < C[1] < 0.0279328))
```

Simplify does not seem to realize that

C[1] being an integer and 0.11058 < C[1] < 0.249093 must mean that this solution must be discarded

or that

C[1] being an integer and -0.11058 < C[1] < 0.0279328 must mean that C[1] must be zero and thus a1 == 0.694795 radians.

If Reduce or Simplify did a slightly better job then this would be an exceptional result. The numerical results match the other two answers provided.

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible workaround to this problem.

```
eqn = {(Cos[a1 ] - Cos[a2 ] + Cos[a3 ]) - v1 == 
    0, (Cos[3 a1 ] - Cos[3 a2 ] + Cos[3 a3 ]) == 
    0, (Cos[5 a1 ] - Cos[5 a2 ] + Cos[5 a3 ]) == 0};
```

I just trying many initial values and select solutions

```
sols = Select[
  Flatten[Table[
    If[({a1, a2, a3} /. 
        Quiet@FindRoot[eqn, {a1, a10}, {a2, a20}, {a3, a30}]) == {a10,
        a20, a30}, Nothing,
     Quiet@FindRoot[eqn, {a1, a10}, {a2, a20}, {a3, a30}]],
    {a10, 0, \[Pi]/2, 0.1}, {a20, 0, \[Pi]/2, 0.1}, {a30, 0, \[Pi]/2, 
     0.1}], 2], #[[1, 2]] < #[[2, 2]] < #[[3, 2]] && #[[1, 2]] > 
     0 && #[[3, 2]] < \[Pi]/2 &]
```

The output of this very slightly differet solutions which is i think only one:

```
{-0.25 + Cos[a1] - Cos[a2] + Cos[a3], 
  Cos[3 a1] - Cos[3 a2] + Cos[3 a3], 
  Cos[5 a1] - Cos[5 a2] + Cos[5 a3]} /. {a1 -> 0.6947954385269768, 
  a2 -> 0.8703021240983365, a3 -> 1.444046302394822}
(*{-2.22045*10^-16, 5.55112*10^-17, 4.44089*10^-16}*)
```

Comment: thanks to all....the above suggestions are really hard for me tounderstand....will work n try though....it they be simplified...

Answer (score 1):

Improvement of the answer of @Bill

Simply restrict the domain of "Reduce" to "Reals"

```
 red1 = Reduce[{Cos[a1] - Cos[a2] + Cos[a3] - 1/4 == 0, 
         Cos[3 a1] - Cos[3 a2] + Cos[3 a3] == 0, 
         Cos[5 a1] - Cos[5 a2] + Cos[5 a3] == 0, 
         0 < a1 < a2 < a3 < Pi/2}, {a1, a2, a3}, Reals] // FullSimplify;
```

Now C[1] is expicitly restricted to Integers

```
red1 // N

 (* 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers && a2 == 0.870302 && 
  a3 == 1.44405 && ((a1 == 
  2. (-0.347398 + 3.14159 C[1]) && -0.347398 + 3.14159 C[1] > 
  0. && -0.347398 + 3.14159 C[1] < 0.435151) || (a1 == 
  2. (0.347398\[VeryThinSpace]+ 3.14159 C[1]) && 
 0.347398\[VeryThinSpace]+ 3.14159 C[1] > 0. && 
 0.347398\[VeryThinSpace]+ 3.14159 C[1] < 0.435151))    *)
```

You get a result only for C[1]==0

```
 N[red1] /. C[1] -> 0

(*    a2 == 0.870302 && a3 == 1.44405 && a1 == 0.694795    *)

 N[red1] /. C[1] -> 1

(*    False    *)
```